# GoogleSheets - Count characters in cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following cells with emojis.

[image]

As you can see I would like to get the value of these emojis as numeric.

I tried using a regex: `=len(regexreplace(A2,"[^\⭐️]",""))`

However, I do not get the desired result.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?
Find below the link to the example spreadsheet:

[Link to the Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ezyfBuaNB624KIvbb8Dr2UdfdDLo2ROZml5AJobN9zI/edit#gid=1415133774)

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

added formula to your sheet. Please test it out:

`=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(A2:A),1,LAMBDA(r,c,LAMBDA(ax,IF(ax=0,"-",ax))(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(A2:A,r),"[^⭐]",""))+ LEN(REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(A2:A,r),"[^½¾]",""))/2)))`

-
[image]

**ALTERNATE FORMULA**

`=BYROW(IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "(.)", "$1|"), "|"))),LAMBDA(ax,IF(ax="",,LAMBDA(zx,IF(zx=0,"-",zx))(COUNTIF(ax,"⭐")+COUNTIF(ax,"")+IF((COUNTIF(ax,"½")>0)+(COUNTIF(ax,"¾")>0),0.5,)))))`

-

[image]